# Failed OpenCV install unable to uninstall

Tags: opencv, makefile, uninstallation, opencv-contrib

While installing opencv_contrib (during `make -j5` step), my laptop went to sleep and gave errors on the install, failing with a fatal error.
Retrying `make -j5` gave the same error again. trying to uninstall opencv completely using `make uninstall` also completely fails with a fatal error.

How do I do a fresh install of OpenCV from here?

Error on running `make uninstall`:

```
-- Uninstalling "/usr/local/include/opencv2/cvconfig.h"
CMake Error at cmake_uninstall.cmake:20 (MESSAGE):
  Problem when removing "/usr/local/include/opencv2/cvconfig.h"


CMakeFiles/uninstall.dir/build.make:57: recipe for target 
'CMakeFiles/uninstall' failed
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/uninstall] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:296: recipe for target 
'CMakeFiles/uninstall.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/uninstall.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:303: recipe for target             
'CMakeFiles/uninstall.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/uninstall.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:234: recipe for target 'uninstall' failed
make: *** [uninstall] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `make clean` and try to uninstall again.  Also you should restart from previous steps for opencv installing

Comment: I screwed up, I forgot to uninstall before deleting all files in the folder to do a fresh download and install. I'm getting more errors now. `CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
`

Comment: It shows this error for headings, `CUDA_CUDA_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)` and `CUDA_nppi_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)`, with a lot of files listed under each of these

Comment: I realise this is a completely different problem, so I'll move this to a new thread unless I find a solution elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly delete files from usr/local/...etc so you try giving **sudo make uninstall** it will work fine!